# Spring batch problem - No property id found for type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm writing to you about a problem that's driving me crazy. As I will show in the following code, I have a batch job that needs to read data from a db and clone it onto the same db. The batch is divided into different steps but when I get to this step, specifically into the Reader, it gives me this error:

```
  exitCode=FAILED;exitDescription=org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type WsaCtpImcrAllocation!
```

In the code I clearly search for "sandboxId" and all the rest of the code seems written correctly. The WsaCtpImcrAllocation entity is a table that shares the same fields as another similar one (CtpImcrAllocation) so this is an extended class of the second.

Below i'll show the code.

Jobconfiguration:

```
private WsaSandbox sandbox;
    
    ...
    
    @Bean
        @StepScope
        public RepositoryItemReader<WsaCtpImcrAllocation> wsaCtpImcrAllocationCloneReader(WsaCtpImcrAllocationRepo wsaCtpImcrAllocationRepo){
            RepositoryItemReader<WsaCtpImcrAllocation> wsaCtpImcrAllocationCloneRepositoryItemReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
            wsaCtpImcrAllocationCloneRepositoryItemReader.setRepository(wsaCtpImcrAllocationRepo);
            wsaCtpImcrAllocationCloneRepositoryItemReader.setMethodName("findAllBySandboxId");
            wsaCtpImcrAllocationCloneRepositoryItemReader.setArguments(Arrays.asList(sandbox));
            wsaCtpImcrAllocationCloneRepositoryItemReader.setSort(sortMap);
            return wsaCtpImcrAllocationCloneRepositoryItemReader;
        }
```

Classe del Writer:

```
@StepScope
public class CloneWsaCtpImcrAllocationCustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<WsaCtpImcrAllocation>, StepExecutionListener{
    
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CloneWsaTradeWhatIfCustomItemWriter.class);
    
    @Autowired
    WsaCtpImcrAllocationRepo wsaCtpImcrAllocationRepo;
    @Autowired
    WsaSandboxRepo wsaSandboxRepo;
    
    private WsaSandbox newSandbox;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends WsaCtpImcrAllocation> items) throws Exception {
        try {
            items.stream().forEach(allocation->wsaCtpImcrAllocationRepo.saveCopy(allocation, newSandbox));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.catching(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        newSandbox = (WsaSandbox) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("newSandbox");
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface WsaCtpImcrAllocationRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<WsaCtpImcrAllocation, CtpImcrAllocationId>, WsaCtpImcrAllocationRepoCustom {
    
    List<WsaCtpImcrAllocation> findAllBySandboxId(WsaSandbox sandboxId);
    Page<WsaCtpImcrAllocation> findAllBySandboxId(WsaSandbox sandboxId, Pageable pageable);
...
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WSA_CTP_IMCR_ALLOCATION")
public class WsaCtpImcrAllocation extends CtpImcrAllocation{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SANDBOX_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(ExtractionJsonView.FullWithChildren.class)
    private WsaSandbox sandboxId;
    
    @Column(name = "CUSTOM")
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(ExtractionJsonView.Full.class)
    private Boolean isCustom = false ;
    ....
}
```

Entity parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CTP_IMCR_ALLOCATION")
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@IdClass(CtpImcrAllocationId.class)
public class CtpImcrAllocation {
    
    @Column(name = "BUSINESS_DATE")
    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(ExtractionJsonView.Full.class)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date businessDate;

    @Column(name = "PERIMETER")
    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(ExtractionJsonView.Full.class)
    private String perimeter;

    @Column(name="IDENTIFIER")
    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(ExtractionJsonView.Full.class)
    private String identifier;
    ...
}
```

IdClass:

```
public class CtpImcrAllocationId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9063822398839581588L;

    private Date businessDate;
    private String perimeter;
    private String identifier;
    
    public Date getBusinessDate() {
        return businessDate;
    }
    public void setBusinessDate(Date businessDate) {
        this.businessDate = businessDate;
    }
    public String getPerimeter() {
        return perimeter;
    }
    public void setPerimeter(String perimeter) {
        this.perimeter = perimeter;
    }
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }
    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }


}
```

I hope you notice something that I struggle to see because I no longer know where to go. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rename your field to `sandbox` instead of `sandboxId`.

Comment: Already tried, nothing changed. ChatGPT said to me that RepositoryItemReader needs an id, but my class has a ClassId. Maybe that's the point

Comment: No the problem is the name and with that the name of the query method. YOu need to rename the field and the repository method accordingly (without the `Id` part). At least that would be my guess, if it isn't put the full stacktrace in instead of a snippet. Next to that I wonder what is in `sortMap`?

Comment: the problem is in you repository, you used this methode `findAllBySandboxId` and you don't have any field named Id, try to understand the Spring data JPA methods query :  [documentation page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)